# What is the default and maximum value of delta query odata.maxpagesize?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I tried to find the max and default value for delta queries odata.maxpagesize, but couldn't find it. Example from [graph documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_events):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview/delta?startdatetime=2016-12-01T00:00:00Z&enddatetime=2016-12-30T00:00:00Z HTTP/1.1
Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=2
```

The [graph documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_events) specifies:

> Each delta query GET request returns a collection of one or more events in the response. You can optionally specify the request header, Prefer: odata.maxpagesize={x}, to set the maximum number of events in a response.

So my question is:

- What is the maximum value for odata.maxpagesize?
- If odata.maxpagesize is not set what is the maximum amount of events
  returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximum value for odata.maxpagesize is 200 for objects and 500 for links and the same number is returned if odata.maxpagesize is not set.

Having said that, setting odata.maxpagesize =200 does not guarantee that 200 results will be returned even if the data is supposed to be there. That is because maxpagesize is used in conjunction with some timeout value. If the underlying results can not be fetched by the service within this timeout period, then less than 200 can also be returned. Therefore different calls can return different number of results in the response with ofcourse a NextLink provided if applicable.

Thanks,
--Meetali.